How to create unique id on each block of quill editor?
I want to add a uniq id to each p block of quill editor.
I have tried this piece of code but it only adds the same id to each p block.
const BlockBlot = Quill.import('blots/block');

class CustomBlockBlot extends BlockBlot {
  static create(value) {
    const node = super.create(value);
    node.setAttribute('id', Math.random());
    return node;
  }
}
Quill.register('formats/block', CustomBlockBlot);

const quill = new Quill('#surface-render', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  }
});

How would you do this?

What id is it adding? Math.random may give a technically valid attribute value but which cannot be used as a CSS selector - how are you intending to use it?

Math.random() returns a fraction, it always begins with 0.. It's generally not a good idea to use a string with . as an ID, because . is used in selectors to match the class.

I might have a solution for your issue! This approach dynamically adds IDs to headings (h1, h2, h3) in React Quill editor, ensuring they match the heading content.
You may need to modify it to matched your needs.
function addIdsToHeadings(quill, options) {
  if (!options.enable) return;

  const processHeadings = () => {
    const headings = quill.container.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3');
    headings.forEach((heading) => {
      const text = heading.innerText || heading.textContent || '';
      const newId = text.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

      if (text.trim() && heading.id !== newId) {
        // Update ID only if it differs from the current one
        heading.id = newId;
      }
    });
  };

  const debouncedProcess = debounce(processHeadings, 200); // Debounce to optimize performance

  // Monitor text changes to add or update IDs
  quill.on('text-change', debouncedProcess);
}

and then add enable options
const modules = {
  toolbar: {
    container: '#toolbar'
  },
  addIdsToHeadings: {
    enable: true
  }
};

its just a suggestion, but maybe you want to consider id generator such as nanoid or uuid
